# Get specific entry from a <List> knowing its position

Tags: java, android, arrays, list

I've got a simple list that gets objects / rows from database with a specific date and stores them.

```
List<Appointment> appointments = database.getSpecificAppointments(selectedDate);
```

I display each entry as a new line with format like `1. Time "Title"` user than has an option to enter numbers starting from 1 - ... based on the entered number I want to delete entry in a list, so if user entered 1, get first list item and perform `.deleteAppointment()` method on it.

I think with arrays it would be something like `appointments[userInput - 1].deleteAppointment()` (Where userInput is selected number, and we -1 because array starts from 0), but I can't figure out this with lists.

Comment: `appontments.get(userInput - 1).deleteAppointment()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the "get" method on the list?

example:

```
appointments.get(userInput - 1).deleteAppointment()
```